# Optimise deletion of non unique records in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am creating a Recordset with all of the entries that appear multiple times and then go through each element in this RS and delete all older entries.
Only entries that are non unique on BTNR and ARPNR should be deleted.
I also don't want to delete the newest of the multiple records.
Does anybody know how I could make this faster, because it takes a very long time as it has to regularly run through 600+ records. I am very new to VBA and SQL, so there is probably a better way to do this.

```vb
Sub DeleteMult()
Dim allMult As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT ARPs.ARPNR, ARPs.Änderungsdatum FROM ARPs WHERE ARPs.BTNR IN (SELECT BTNR FROM ARPs GROUP BY BTNR HAVING COUNT(BTNR) > 1);"

Set allMult = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With allMult

    'Check that RecordSet isn't empty
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then

        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        'Loop to the end of the RecordSet
        While (Not allMult.EOF)
            'Delete all multiple entries except the newest
            With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
                "DELETE FROM ARPs WHERE ARPNR = prm0 AND Änderungsdatum < prm1")
                .Parameters("prm0") = allMult.Fields("ARPNR")
                .Parameters("prm1") = allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum")
                .Execute
                .Close
            End With

            With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
                "DELETE FROM KoGr WHERE ARPNR = prm0 AND Änderungsdatum < prm1")
                .Parameters("prm0") = allMult.Fields("ARPNR")
                .Parameters("prm1") = allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum")
                .Execute
                .Close
            End With

            With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
                "DELETE FROM SA WHERE ARPNR = prm0 AND Änderungsdatum < prm1")
                .Parameters("prm0") = allMult.Fields("ARPNR")
                .Parameters("prm1") = allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum")
                .Execute
                .Close
            End With

            .MoveNext
        Wend

    End If

    .Close
End With

'empty Memory
Set allMult = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is a sample Dataset. Data marked read should be deleted. Of course there are usually ~60 KoGr and SA for each BTNR. If the newest ARPNR has more than 1 BTNR in it all of them should be kept.
[image: This is a sample Dataset. Data marked read should be deleted. Of course there are usually ~60 KoGr and SA for each BTNR. If the newest ARPNR has more than 1 BTNR in it all of them should be kept.]

I have now tried An SQL statement as I stumbled over the MAX() functionality.

```
strSQL = "Delete A 
          FROM ARPs AS A 
               JOIN (SELECT BTNR, ARPNR, Änderungsdatum 
                     FROM ARPs AS A1 
                     WHERE A1.BTNR = A.BTNR 
                           AND A1.ARPNR = A.ARPNR 
                           AND A1.Änderungsdatum <> (SELECT MAX(Änderungsdatum) 
                                                     FROM ARPs 
                                                     WHERE BTNR = A1.BTNR 
                                                           AND ARPNR = A1.ARPNR)) AS R 
               ON R.ARPNR = A.ARPNR 
                  AND R.Änderungsdatum = T.Änderungdatum;"
```

But it returns an Error in the FROM clause.

Comment: First, be sure you have index on _ARPNR_ and _Änderungsdatum_ in all tables. It could be a two-field (compound) index.

Comment: The compound index would have to be BTNR, ARPNR and Änderungsdatum though, because ARPNR is a file with multiple BTNR in it and only one Änderungsdatum. @Gustav But how would this increase performance?

Comment: You should _only_ include fields you search. If BTNR must be included, add a parameter for that as well. Index is a key factor for speedy searching; if left out, a search will have to read the full table.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you, that is already somewhat faster.

Comment: Include some sample data in the question, clearly marking the ones that should be deleted. This can probably be achieved in three queries (one per table) instead of one delete query per duplicate, and will execute several times as fast if you do it that way.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I can query the non unique data in each table, but how would I check that they are not the newest version of that data and only delete all except the newest for each set of multiple data.

Comment: Just use a subquery selecting only the newest, and then use a `NOT IN` clause. But as said, if you provide table structures, I can show you. I'm assuming the tables do have a unique identifier.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have added the Table structure and an SQL query I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Your inner subquery should also have an alias for `ARPs` and use it for all fields you use from that table.

Comment: Try executing your inner subquery first, to test for errors, and specify the `JOIN` as `INNER JOIN` (and also, what @Andre said). Furthermore, remove `WHERE A1.BTNR = A.BTNR 
                           AND A1.ARPNR = A.ARPNR ` from your subquery, and join on them, since they're out of scope in your subquery.